# Asp.Net MVC AutoMapper Adding Records to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Using AutoMapper - is it possible to add a list of posted items, to the database - similar to:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Analyst(ObjectiveVM ovm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var objectives = ovm.obList;
            db.Objectives.Add(Mapper.Map<IList<ObjectiveVM.ObList>, IList<Objective>>(objectives));
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(ovm);
    }
```

Or do you still have to loop through each item in the ovm list, and add each to the DBContext separately?

Answer (score 0):

I read this post: [The case for two-way mapping in AutoMapper](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/) and realised it probably isn't a good idea anyway, and looping and retaining control over your domain/database, is best.

Thanks, Mark